# TextUtil.isEmpty() is always returning empty, even when the field is filled in the Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, is-empty, textutils

TextUtil.isEmpty() is always returning empty, even when the field is filled in the Android.
Code snippet:

> ```
>     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())) {
>
>                 completeNameEditText.setError("Empty field);
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 return; 
>     }
> ```

The problem is that, even filling all the EditText with Strings, always points to the error: "Empty field".

Please, what to do to fix this?

Comment: What is the variable `name` referencing? Where and how do you assign it, can you share that part of code as well? As far as we know `name` might reference an `EditText` field that is hidden in your layout and you never input anything into it.

Comment: I already discovered the problem: it was a part of the code that it was disturbing. I just delete the code that was disturbing, and everything works fine. Thank you very much. You always helped a lot, Ma3x. Congratulations.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it helped you fix the issue.